# PHP foreach if/else with a table

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I have a PHP script on my Wordpress Site, where I want to show the 10 member anniversary of all my registered club members. If there's no anniversary in the current year, a message shall show up saying something like "No Anniversary this year". What I have done so far:

```
<?php
$args2 = array(
'role' => '',
'meta_key' => 'last_name',
'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$members = get_users($args2);

echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:20px;">';
foreach ($members as $user) {

$clubeintritt = new DateTime($user->club); // club entry date
$jahre = $clubeintritt->diff(new DateTime); // no. of years in the club
$jubi=('10'); // 10 years

if($jahre->y == $jubi) {

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $user->first_name . ' ' .$user->last_name .'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
}

if($jahre->y != $jubi) {
echo 'No Aniversary this yeaar';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

So right now, I get the list with my 10 years club members, but also the message that there's no anniversary this year.

I guess there must be something with "endforeach", but couldn't come to a solution.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set a boolean to "false" before your loop, meaning "No anniversary found". If you find any, you set it to "true":

```
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:20px;">';
$found = false;
foreach ($members as $user) {

    $clubeintritt = new DateTime($user->club); // club entry date
    $jahre = $clubeintritt->diff(new DateTime); // no. of years in the club
    $jubi=('10'); // 10 years

    if($jahre->y == $jubi) {
        $found = true;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $user->first_name . ' ' .$user->last_name .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}

if(!$found) {
    echo 'No Aniversary this yeaar';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter is simple:

```
<?php
$args2 = array(
'role' => '',
'meta_key' => 'last_name',
'orderby'  => 'meta_value',
'order' => 'ASC'
);

$members = get_users($args2);
$aCounter=0;

echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:20px;">';
foreach ($members as $user) {

    $clubeintritt = new DateTime($user->club); // club entry date
    $jahre = $clubeintritt->diff(new DateTime); // no. of years in the club
    $jubi=('10'); // 10 years

    if($jahre->y == $jubi) {
    $aCounter++;
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $user->first_name . ' ' .$user->last_name .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
}

if($aCounter === 0) {
echo 'No Aniversary this yeaar';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change :

```
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:20px;">';
foreach ($members as $user) {

$clubeintritt = new DateTime($user->club); // club entry date
$jahre = $clubeintritt->diff(new DateTime); // no. of years in the club
$jubi=('10'); // 10 years

if($jahre->y == $jubi) {

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $user->first_name . ' ' .$user->last_name .'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
}

if($jahre->y != $jubi) {
echo 'No Aniversary this yeaar';
}
echo '</table>';
```

to

```
$out = '';

foreach ($members as $user) {

$clubeintritt = new DateTime($user->club); // club entry date
$jahre = $clubeintritt->diff(new DateTime); // no. of years in the club
$jubi=('10'); // 10 years

if($jahre->y == $jubi) {

$out .= '<tr>';
$out .= '<td>' . $user->first_name . ' ' .$user->last_name .'</td>';
$out .= '</tr>';
}
}

if(empty($out)) {
echo 'No Aniversary this yeaar';
}
else
{   echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:20px;">';
echo $out;
echo '</table>';
```

}

Comment: 3 different ways you can choose the one you like best;)

Answer (score 0):

Check the last value of `$jahre->y`. It will not be equal to `$jubi`. So the last iteration of the for loop causes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

change lines as below:

```
$members = get_users($args2);
$aniversary = false;
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin-top:20px;">';
foreach ($members as $user) {

$clubeintritt = new DateTime($user->club); // club entry date
$jahre = $clubeintritt->diff(new DateTime); // no. of years in the club
$jubi=('10'); // 10 years

if($jahre->y == $jubi) {

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>' . $user->first_name . ' ' .$user->last_name .'</td>';
echo '</tr>';
$aniversary = true;
}
}

if(!$aniversary) {
echo 'No Aniversary this yeaar';
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```